# Can not figure out the correct way to implement Django Filters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

My problem is I have to query database for users for certain fields which are `des`, `gender`, `min_age`, `max_age`. When I was usind multiple values it was working fine using `filter_queryset`. And then I used multiple values for `gender` its working but when I don't include the `gender` in my url the code break basically because `split` doesn't work.
So I thought using multiple `if/else` which will have different `queryset.filter(des__in=[], gender__in=[])` or `gender` not available then query -> `queryset.filter(des__in=[])`. I am missing many things here. please help

API - `/v1/users/query_users?des=1,2&gender=Male,Female&min_age=2&max_age=4`

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    min_age = django_filters.DateRangeFilter(name="dob", lookup_expr="gte")
    max_age = django_filters.DateRangeFilter(name="dob", lookup_expr="lte")
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['des', 'gender', 'min_age', 'max_age']


class QueryUserGroup(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = ProductFilter
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        des_list = self.request.GET.getlist("des")
        gender_list = self.request.GET.getlist("gender")
        des_ids = des_list[0].split(',')
        gender_ids = gender_list[0].split(',')
        return queryset.filter(des__in=des_ids, gender__in=gender_ids)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return JSONResponse({'data': serializer.data}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rearrange your code so that you only split the string and filter the queryset if the field is in the querystring.

Since you are only ever accessing the first item in the list, you might as well use `get` instead of `getlist`.

```
def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
    des = self.request.GET.get("des")
    if des is not None:
        des_ids = des.split(',')
        queryset = queryset.filter(des__in=des_ids)

    gender = self.request.GET.get("gender")
    if gender is not None:
        gender_ids = gender.split(',')
        queryset = queryset.filter(gender__in=gender_ids)

    return queryset
```

If you had more than two fields, you could cut down on duplicated code by looping through the list of fieldnames:

```
def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
    for fieldname in ("des", "gender"):
        value = self.request.GET.get(fieldname)
        if value is not None:
            ids = value.split(',')
            queryset = queryset.filter(**{'%s__in' % fieldname: ids})

    return queryset
```